# Inline-level element being forced to a new line in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How come the `<strong>` element, which is an inline element, is forced to a new line?

This setup has a flex within a flex, nothing particularly crazy I wouldn't have thought. So perhaps it's just my misunderstanding of how flexbox works.

Take a look at: http://codepen.io/leads/pen/mEYOay

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 600px
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.middle {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.middle button {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
.middle p {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
strong {
  background: red;
}
.right {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>some content in the top left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
    <button>CTA</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>CTA</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<strong>` element is a child in a flex container with `flex-direction: column`.

Hence, it will stack vertically with its siblings (which includes [anonymous flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items), like in your code.)

*Also note that:*

- When elements are children of a flex container, their display value is *blockified*.
- In other words, `display: inline`, `display: table`, etc., will become `display: block` within the rules of a *[flex formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)*.

As an alternative, you can use [*flex `auto` margins*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) to create your layout:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 600px
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.middle {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.middle button {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin-top: auto;   /* NEW */
}
.middle p {
  margin-top: auto;   /* NEW */
}
strong {
  background: red;
}
.right {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>some content in the top left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
    <button>CTA</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>CTA</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWbNyP?editors=1100)

Comment: Sweet! Get rid of the flexbox on it. I should have thought of that. I was in too deep, man!